# Holding ctrl or alt while typing in input box prevents any input?

Tags: html, text, input, alt, ctrl

I need a way to have characters input into a input box even if the user is holding down ctrl, alt, or both.
When you hold those keys down, characters can't be typed in.
How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm just curious - why would the user be needing to hold down the ctrl or alt keys?

Comment: I guess you mean something like ctrl+v or any alt codes or special characters on keyboard. But first you need to provide us a sample what you got so far. Actually you can use alt or ctrl when typing in input box.